# Summarise multiple panels in 1

Tags: grafana, prometheus

So I have a number of fairly typical panels (CPU usage, RAM, HDD activity etc.) which show red / orange / green depending on their values. What I would like is a single panel that sits above these which combines the results of the above to give an overall "Okay" status.

E.G. If RAM is in the green, CPU is in the green and HDD activity is green, then the summary box will be green. Likewise if anything is red or amber the summary box will show red.

Ideally I want to achieve this directly inside Grafana rather than Prometheus so I can use data from difference sources.

I have tried running multiple queries in one singlestat panel, with a view to getting "1" for each individual aspect that is correct, and then summing that number to see if all are 1, but this results in the usual "multiple dataset" error for a singlestat, and would also mean repeating the query I have already written elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat the query, you can probably do some Javascript magic in some Text or Ajax panel (haven't tried it), but I can't think of any other alternative.

If you're fine repeating your queries, then the approach you describe should work. If you're getting a "multiple dataset" error, that means your expression is incorrect. Tweak in in Prometheus until it reliably produces a single value rather than a vector of values (one suggestion to get you started is to make use of `sum without(instance)`, plus whatever other labels you want to get rid of).

Comment: Thanks for your help Alin. I'm able to run queries like `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes > 5` (as an example), but this returns the true value (if the query is correct). E.G. `5 > 4` would return 5, instead of 1 (or true). Any idea how I can get a boolean output from such operators in Prometheus?

Comment: As per [PromQL operators documentation] (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators), you can get a boolean output from a comparison operator by appending `bool` to said operator. E.g.

    node_memory_MemTotal_bytes > bool 5

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for your help. If no further answers arise that provide a better solution I will be sure to accept yours. For now, I have upvoted both your answer and comment.

Comment: Actually, I'm not so sure this does work with Prometheus due to a quirk in how it processes queries. For example, `(node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"ext4|vfat"} > bool 50)` works fine, as does `(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes > bool 50)`, but adding them together (`(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes > bool 50) + (node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"ext4|vfat"} > bool 50)`) does not, even though another addition (`(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes > bool 50) + (node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes> bool 50)`) works fine. I think this might be an issue with how Prometheus?

Comment: Binary operations between vectors (such as addition) will only return results for label combinations that match on both sides. In your case, I imagine `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes` only has a `node` label, while `node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes` might have `node` and `disk` labels.

Regardless, for your particular goal you should write all your rules as `sum(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes > bool 50) + sum(node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"ext4|vfat"} > bool 50)`. Then you would only be adding together scalars and wouldn't need to worry about any of this.